# Update 2 tables using Stored Procedure in MySql

Tags: asp.net, mysql, stored-procedures, insert-update

This seems like a simple request. But my query in not working and I'm finding conflicting answers on the internet. Is it possible to have UPDATE and INSERT using a Stored Procedure joining 2 tables in MySql?

I have an Asp.net Webforms website. It has 2 tables Individual and Address. Individual table contains data on an individual, i.e. Phone Number, Fax, Email ect. 
The address table has all the address information for an individual. They each table has a column of Individual ID which auto increments. (Note: the individualID in Address table is not a primary key, but individualID in the individual table is a primary key.

Anyway, I have a  FormView in Asp.net that with a SELECT statement that joins those 2 tables and display the data fine. But updating new information to both tables keeps failing.

My most recent error is : Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Is there a way to write an UPDATE statement that joins 2 Tables?? This has to exist right?

Comment: SQL Update statements can only update one table.  To do two, you update one table and then the other....hopefully in a transaction so if the second fails, you can roll back the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to update multiple tables with a single query -

```
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
SET table1.col1 = 'some value', table2.col1 = 'Another value'
WHERE <some where clause>;
```

Comment: See what I mean? Some people say it isn't possible others say it is.

Comment: When I add Set table1.col1 = 'somevalue'  Is some value the variablename I am passing? such as Fname? or Lname?

Comment: :-) It's definitely possible. I even checked it to make sure before I posted it. 'somevalue' is the value you want to assign to the column which is most probably coming from a variable.

Comment: Ok, Im trying to test my query in MySql WorkBench. I cant get it to test correctly. Im using:  call test_update(12, Starbucks, 123 My Street )  Where 12 = param oindividualID, Starbucks = oCompany and 123MyStreet = param oCompany. What is the correct suntax for testing an update procedure. I'm using MySql Workbench. Thanks.

Comment: To give you any further help you will need to post more details. Table structures and the code for your stored proc would be a good start.